# No "publish" in VS2012 Express - Web One Click Publish can't be configured

Tags: publish, visual-studio-2012

According to the link below, i should be able to configure Web One Click Publish. There are even screenshots showing how to achieve that. However, i can't find that option in my solution explorer. Am i retarded or blind?!

I'll gladly provide screenshots of my installation in case somebody questions my sanity and ability to find an item on a menu...   :)

[MSDN description of configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Did you add the "Web one click publish" toolbar?

Comment: Yes, it's right there BUT it's grayed out, probably due to the fact that there are no configurations. Besides that, the publish menu item seems to be missing independent of whether i'm viewing the toolbar or not. It's like MS designed a publish-free just for me... :)

Comment: This is a really silly question..but...are you shure that you are trying to publish a WEB application? Is Menu `Build>Publish` grayed out?

Comment: It's not grayed out. It just is **not there**. I'm posting two screenshots so you'll see for yourself and maybe we'll realize something subobvious.

Comment: [Screenshot 1](http://chamster.somee.com/temp/sshot01.png)

Comment: [Screenshot 2](http://chamster.somee.com/temp/sshot02.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to publish a **Web Site**, but the link that you posted said:

> How to: Deploy a **Web Application Project** Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio
>
> This topic explains how to create a publish profile and how to publish (deploy) a **web application project**

Web Site is different than a Web Application Project.

[Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx) explains the differences between them. Also, it discusses the configuration to be made in Visual Studio.

Scenarios in which Web application projects are the preferred choice include the following:

- You want to use the automated deployment tools that are available in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Hmmm... It appears that i was ignorant about the difference between those two. To be honest i was under impression that it was basically the same option called two different names for marketing reasons ("you can not only build web sites - you can also create web applications"-thingy). Glad you straighted that out for me. I will use this as an excuse to downgrade back to VS2010 for esthetical reasons.

Comment: You can use Web Application en Visual Studio 2012 too. Create a New Project and select "Web Application"

Comment: Oh, i know. But i'm going to use your explanation as an EXCUSE to motivate a change back to an IDE that doesn't look like Windows 0.9. Anyhow, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Grr, I want one click publish for my site.

Comment: @ScottBeeson Are you having an issue with it? I'm guessing it's not the same mistake I did a few months ago...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the web project is selected as the startup project